# Call to a member function fetch_array() on array

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, class

```
    if($this->cuvant_cautat)
    {
        $this->cuvant_cautat = $this->bd->query("SELECT cuvant_raspuns FROM dc_asociatii WHERE cuvant_stimul='".$this->cuvant_cautat."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5");
        //echo $this->cuvant_cautat[0];
        while($this->cuvant_cautat = $this->cuvant_cautat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
            {
                echo $this->cuvant_cautat[0];
            }
    }
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on array in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\motor\classes\user.Class.php on line 89

The line 89 is as below:

```
while($this->cuvant_cautat = $this->cuvant_cautat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
```

Comment: Well for one thing, you're reassigning the variable containing the result set to the first row in that set. On the second iteration, it will try to call `fetch_array()` on a row, a function that no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `$this->cuvant_cautat` each time.  Use a different variable in the iteration.

```
while ($something_else = $this->cuvant_cautat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))) {
    echo $something_else[0];
}
```